# .NET NewtonSoft JSON deserialize list with auto-increment index

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

My current situation is I have a json file

```
[
    {
        "first_name" : "Foo",
        "last_name" : "Bar",
        "gender" : 0
    },
    {
        "first_name" : "FooFoo",
        "last_name" : "BarBar",
        "gender" : 1
    }
]
```

and a Person class:

```
class Person
{
    public Id { get; private set; }
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public int Gender; 
}
```

and I'm using the deserializer like this:

```
JArray.ToObject<List<Person>>();
```

or the equivalent:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(jsonstr, ...)
```

although there is non in the json object itself, in the Person class there is a "Id" field and I need it to have increasing values according to the Person's position in the list.

The reason I can't make Id public property and set it after deserialize is because, it's an Id it should NOT be editable and I think is bad programming.

I've heard of JsonConverters. Is this achievable using them? I needed some help. Summing up I needed a way to deserialize Json arrays into objects' lists and automatically set them auto incrementing Ids.

Well then, thank you for your time.

Comment: Your access modifier of ID is set as private so the serialize method most be  observe the access modifier level

Comment: There are many solution but I think you can have a properties whith Public Access Modifier and then in the seter method can do what you want

Comment: @AliSheikhNezami changed the OP private field to a public with private setter... but that was not the issue... the problem will still persist. I could make it so after deserializing I would set the ID manually and after being set (aka... Id != null) the Id couldn't be set anymore. Don't know how good of a practice this would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to change anything in the deserialization process, you can simply do something in the constructor of the class:

```
static int NextId = 0;

public Person() 
{
     Id = NextId++;
}
```

And, yes, you definitely don't want your Id to be editable. A good pattern here would be

```
public int Id { get; private set;}
```

You can also put a [JsonIgnore] attribute on Id. This will mean this will not be assigned to.

```
[JsonIgnore]
public int Id { get; private set;}
```

To reset IDs

```
public static void ResetNextId(int startId)
{
    NextId = startId;
}

Person.ResetNextId(0);
```

There is also an [OnDeserialized] attribute you can apply to a procedure on the object to assign properties after the object has been deserialization.

```
[OnDeserialized]
public void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
{
     // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I want to Id to be relative to it's position on the List not a global Id so there would be many List<Person> and the Id for the first item of each one of them would be 0.

Comment: Ah yes, of course you could add a static ResetId procedure to do this.

Comment: Hmmm.. that would be an interesting option! I could even use a wrapper method for deserializing lists that would call that procedure in the end.

Comment: Good idea! You could also use Guids if you want to avoid the resetting call!

Comment: can I apply that OnDeserialized to a List<Object> instead of a single object?!

Comment: I think you could apply it to an object that implements IList<Person> perhaps, maybe you could implement an extension method to List<T>. You could definitely do it on Person, perhaps including context, in the StreamingContext object.